# Show page number as a "percent complete"

Tags: header-footer, numbering, page-numbering

I want to show in the page foot the current progress of the document. For example, if the document contains 200 pages, then I want the foot to show 11.5% in the page 23.

Edit: I'm also interested the foot to show percent complete of current chapter. Is it possible?

Tank you for help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 15):

The package `zref-totpages` can deliver the total number of pages and with `expl3` we have a powerful number crunching system.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{zref-totpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\percentage}{}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \ztotpages > 0 }
   {
    \fp_to_decimal:n { round( 100 * \value{page} / \ztotpages , 2 ) }
   }
   { -- }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\cfoot{\LARGE\textcolor{blue}{\percentage\% -- Page \thepage\ of \ztotpages}}
\ifoot{}
\ofoot{}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew of `lastpage` until today. After the comment of Werner, I searched a bit, and it seems that `lastpage` sets the label with `\AtEndDocument`, so it “solves” nothing. The manual says that the one that tries harder to get to the very very end is `pagelts`. Opinion? What are the possible problems?

Comment: @Manuel It *may* have problems in tough situations. Never encountered one. A possibly safer package is `zref`; I'll update this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm also interested the foot to show percent complete of current section, also percent complete of total document. Is it possible?

Comment: @Albert That's rather vaguely defined.

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\cfoot{\percentpagemark}

\AtEndDocument{\label{last-page}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \percentpagemark { }
  {
    \int_set:NV \l_tmpa_int { \value{page} }
    \int_set:NV \l_tmpb_int { \pageref{last-page} }
    \fp_eval:n { round( 100*\l_tmpa_int/\l_tmpb_int , 2 ) } \, \%
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_set:Nn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{blindtext} % For this example

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted by @Werner, this `\AtEndDocument` solution may not be perfect in some cases (something with the last shipout or may be some contents that are added after the reference included in my code). Of course, there are already packages for that; a better result may be achieved using the references made by [`pagelts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) (which uses [`atveryend`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend) commands).

Comment: Better to use [`atveryend`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend). Also, this creates an error at first compile (since the reference is non-existent).

Comment: @Werner I added a little comment about it. However, since I've never used them and I don't know how shipouts and family works, I'm not going to add that solution to my answer. You can add another one :)

Comment: As soon as TeX reaches `\end{document}` it issues whatever has been accumulated in the `\AtEndDocument` hook. As such, if you have pending floats that need to be flushed, your `\label{last-page}` may be too early. Try adding (say) 10 `\begin{figure}[p] \centering\rule{.5\linewidth}{.5\textheight} \end{figure}` before the end of the document just to get an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm also interested the foot to show percent complete of current section, also percent complete of total document. Is it possible?

Comment: @Albert What is percent complete of current section? (please detail a little bit in the question.) And, percent complete of total document… that's what it already does, or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 10):

Another approach, with page counters and usage of `calculator` package.
The percentage is calculated via `\CalculatePercentage[]{}{}`, where the first optional argument contains the number of digits for round off, the 2nd argument is the designed for the current page number and the 3rd argument holds the total number of pages.

I used a different approach, deviating from `totcount` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}%
\usepackage{calculator}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{everypage}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%


\newcommand{\CalculatePercentage}[3][1]{%
\def\tempone{1.0}%
\def\temptwo{1.0}%
\DIVIDE{#2}{#3}{\temptwo}%
\MULTIPLY{\temptwo}{100}{\tempone}
\ROUND[#1]{\tempone}{\temptwo}%
\temptwo%
}%


\newcounter{lastpagecounter}%
\newcounter{totalpagecounter}%

\makeatletter

\AddEverypageHook{%
\refstepcounter{totalpagecounter}%
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%   Store the total number of pages to aux -file
  \string\setcounter{lastpagecounter}{\number\value{totalpagecounter}}%
}%
}%

\cfoot{\LARGE \textcolor{blue}{\CalculatePercentage{\number\value{page}}{\number\value{lastpagecounter}}\% -- Page \thepage~of \number\value{lastpagecounter}}}%
\ifoot{}%
\ofoot{}%

\newcounter{loopcounter}%
\pagestyle{scrheadings}%


\newcounter{maxpages}
\setcounter{maxpages}{201}


\begin{document}
\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\number\value{loopcounter} < \number\value{maxpages}}{%
\blindtext
\newpage
}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not using `lastpage` and `refcount` for being able to use the value as a number?

Comment: @egreg: I know of them, but sometimes I want to do some things the hard way ;-) I will post another version late on, with `lastpage` and `refcount`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm also interested the foot to show percent complete of current section, also percent complete of total document. Is it possible?

Comment: @Albert: Why did you not write that in your OP before? How do you define `%` of section or of total document. As portions of pages belonging to the current section? If so, this would be difficult, since sections do not start on new pages in general.

Comment: Then i can do it with chapters in book mode instead of sections?

Comment: @Albert, yes you can. Go ahead ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Because the question doesn't include the word LaTeX, I can show the non-LaTeX solution. The first task (percent of total page) is simple with opmac's `\lastpage`:

```
\input opmac

\openref
\footline={\rm\thefontsize[10]\hfil\the\pageno\ / \dopercent\pageno of\lastpage\hfil}

\def\dopercent #1of#2{\ifnum#2=0 ??\else
   \tmpdim=#1 pt 
   \multiply\tmpdim by10 \divide\tmpdim by#2\multiply\tmpdim by10
   \edef\tmp{\expandafter \ignorept \the\tmpdim;}%
   \expandafter\onlyoneten \tmp 
   \fi ~\%%
}
\def\onlyoneten #1.#2#3;{#1.#2}

... document

\bye
```

The second task with percents of pages for chapters is a bit more complicated. I save the list of totalpages for each chapter to the REF file. This is done by `\chaphook` which is executed at the beginning of the chapter: the `\totchappage` from previous chapter is saved. The `\chappagelist` includes in second TeX run:

```
pre_chapter_pages,first_chapter_pages,second_chapter_pages,etc.
```

The `\readttotchappage` reads from this list first item and removes this item from the list. First, we need to run `\readtotchappage` alone in order to remove `pre_chapter_pages`. Then the `\readtotchappage` is used in `\chaphook`.

```
\def\chappagelist{}
\input opmac

... the same code as above ...

\newcount\chappage \newcount\totchappage
\def\chaphook{\vfil\break
   \savechappage
   \chappage=0 \readtotchappage
   \footline={\rm\thefontsize[10]\hfil\the\pageno\ / \dopercent\pageno of\lastpage\hfil
      \global\advance\chappage by1 
      chapter: \dopercent\chappage of\totchappage \hfil}
}
\def\readtotchappage{\ifx\chappagelist\empty \totchappage=0 \else
  \expandafter \readtotchappageA \chappagelist;\fi
}
\def\savechappage{%
   \immediate\write\reffile{\noexpand\addto\noexpand\chappagelist{\the\chappage,}}%
}
\def\readtotchappageA #1,#2;{\totchappage=#1 \def\chappagelist{#2}}
\readtotchappage
\expandafter \def\expandafter \bye \expandafter{\expandafter \savechappage \bye}

... document ...
\bye
```

Comment: Thank you, but this fails in a latex document with pdflatex compilation

Comment: This is non-LaTeX solution, as I annonced. Use `tex` or `pdftex`. Or you can only get an inspiration from this.

Comment: I tried to compile with pdftex, but the compilation fails because the command \chapter{Title chapter} is not correct...

Comment: The command `\chapter` isn't defined in plainTeX. OPmac defines `\chap` command but with another syntax. My solution is intended for OPmac users, no for LaTeX users, sorry. The TeX macro engine (latex/plain) wasn't specified in the question. If you are using LaTeX then you can only be inspired by my code but you cannot use it directly.

Comment: Ok, the mistake was mine for do not include the Word LaTeX, i will open a new question. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Albert There is no need for a separate question: 'site convention' is that answers using alternative formats, _etc._ are fine provided they say that's what they do.