# Show page number of chapter and as a “percent complete” in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer, numbering, page-numbering

I want to show in the page foot the current progress of the current chapter in book mode in LaTeX document. For example, if the chapter contains 200 pages, then I want the foot to show 11.5% in the page 23 (of chapter).

Thanks for help. Regards,

Comment: How is this different from your other question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188620/show-page-number-as-a-percent-complete)?

Comment: Hi, my other question is refered at the page of total document, and the solution proposed for chapters is for the plain-TeX, and I can not to apply in LaTeX

Comment: @Albert Files with the beginning like `\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}` are plain TeX files?!

Comment: Just one solution is for chapters, and this solution is for plain-tex

Comment: I hope that somebody will be inspired by this plain-tex solution and will be able to adapt it for the LaTeX purposes.